# xfs_growfs: is not a mounted xfs filesystem when trying to grow ol-root

Tags: xfs

I have 25+ VM's running OL7.5.  As they grow/get repurposed I sometimes need to add more HDD to them.

I have added space to ol-root and ol-swap many times before, following [in summary] :

```
fdisk to create partition
partprobe -s
pvcreate /dev/sdb1
vgextend ol /dev/sdb1
pvscan
lvextend /dev/mapper/ol-root /dev/sdb1
```

but on some VM's I can no longer add that ol-root space to the file system:

```
xfs_growfs /dev/mapper/ol-root
Error:   xfs_growfs: /dev/mapper/ol-root is not a mounted XFS filesystem
```

I have done this many many times before with no issue on the same VM's.  On this VM I built from scratch and have added sda3 and sda4.

On this particular box I need to upgrade 11g to 18c.  I need 10G ol-swap and more HDD to install the 18c database.

```
$ lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sr0          11:0    1 1024M  0 rom
sda           8:0    0   55G  0 disk
├─sda4        8:4    0   10G  0 part
│ └─ol-root 252:0    0   46G  0 lvm  /
├─sda2        8:2    0   15G  0 part
│ ├─ol-swap 252:1    0    8G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
│ └─ol-root 252:0    0   46G  0 lvm  /
├─sda3        8:3    0   29G  0 part
│ ├─ol-swap 252:1    0    8G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
│ └─ol-root 252:0    0   46G  0 lvm  /
└─sda1        8:1    0    1G  0 part /boot


$ df -Th /dev/mapper/ol-root
Filesystem          Type  Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/ol-root xfs    46G   45G  1.5G  97% /
```

Any suggestions please?

Many thanks

Darren

p.s. The box im trying to expand is a clone of the VM above.  After multiple attempts to grow the file system i killed the box.  The source box shares the same issue with xfs_growfs even when i dont add an sdb partition.  The xfs_growfs should return a much different error when there is no space to allocate.

Comment: Check is the LV is mounted as read-only

Comment: And use `lvextend -L+10GB /dev/mapper/ol-root` (for example) to add 10GB to the LV

Comment: Hi, i do '-L' when im adding space to ol-swap but usually i just want to add all the space that is available to ol-root

Comment: "Check is the LV is mounted as read-only" not sure how i do this?   The file system is read-write.

Comment: Check how much is the free space in VG and add it to the LV (with -L) and then try to extend the filesystem

Comment: man page for `xfs_growfs` state that argument is mount point. (e.g. `xfs_growfs /`)

Comment: Thanks Romeo and Archemar.  I dont understand why though !!

Comment: Thanks @RomeoNinov, no matter what I did, `growfs` wouldn't add the spare space available in the partition. Doing the `lvextend` command first allowed `growfs` to work, even if it didn't expand the filesystem by itself.

Answer (score 14):

You need to target the mount-point not the LVM mapper for the xfs_growfs command. 
This seems to be a new "feature" since we used to be able to xfs_growfs on the mapper.

But the man page specifically refers to mount-point:

> xfs_growfs(8)                                       System Manager's
>   Manual                                      xfs_growfs(8)
>
> NAME
>          xfs_growfs, xfs_info - expand an XFS filesystem
>
> SYNOPSIS
>          xfs_growfs [ -dilnrx ] [ -D size ] [ -e rtextsize ] [ -L size ] [ -m maxpct ] [ -t mtab ] [ -R size ] **mount-point**

Answer (score 4):

OK so doing -L and xxfs_growfs has worked.
VM had ol-root 6GB free

Code for the actual VM, step by step:
Adding 16GB to new HDD in vSphere

```
# fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 59.1 GB, 59055800320 bytes, 115343360 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x000cbfb1

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048     2099199     1048576   83  Linux
/dev/sda2         2099200    33554431    15727616   8e  Linux LVM
/dev/sda3        33554432    94371839    30408704   8e  Linux LVM
/dev/sda4        94371840   115343359    10485760   8e  Linux LVM

Disk /dev/sdb: 17.2 GB, 17179869184 bytes, 33554432 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/ol-root: 49.4 GB, 49379540992 bytes, 96444416 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/ol-swap: 8589 MB, 8589934592 bytes, 16777216 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

# ls /sys/class/scsi_device
1:0:0:0  2:0:0:0  2:0:1:0
# echo 1 > /sys/class/scsi_device/1\:0\:0\:0/device/rescan
# echo 1 > /sys/class/scsi_device/2\:0\:0\:0/device/rescan
# echo 1 > /sys/class/scsi_device/2\:0\:1\:0/device/rescan
```

fdisk /dev/sdb,
n, p, 1, t, 1, 8e, w

```
# fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 59.1 GB, 59055800320 bytes, 115343360 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x000cbfb1

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048     2099199     1048576   83  Linux
/dev/sda2         2099200    33554431    15727616   8e  Linux LVM
/dev/sda3        33554432    94371839    30408704   8e  Linux LVM
/dev/sda4        94371840   115343359    10485760   8e  Linux LVM

Disk /dev/sdb: 17.2 GB, 17179869184 bytes, 33554432 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x86979f60

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1            2048    33554431    16776192   8e  Linux LVM

Disk /dev/mapper/ol-root: 49.4 GB, 49379540992 bytes, 96444416 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/ol-swap: 8589 MB, 8589934592 bytes, 16777216 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

Partprobe

```
# partprobe -s
/dev/sda: msdos partitions 1 2 3 4
/dev/sdb: msdos partitions 1
```

pvcreate

```
# pvcreate /dev/sdb1
  Physical volume "/dev/sdb1" successfully created.
```

vgextend

```
# vgextend ol /dev/sdb1
  Volume group "ol" successfully extended
```

pvscan

```
# pvscan
  PV /dev/sda2   VG ol              lvm2 [<15.00 GiB / 0    free]
  PV /dev/sda3   VG ol              lvm2 [<29.00 GiB / 0    free]
  PV /dev/sda4   VG ol              lvm2 [<10.00 GiB / 0    free]
  PV /dev/sdb1   VG ol              lvm2 [<16.00 GiB / <16.00 GiB free]
  Total: 4 [69.98 GiB] / in use: 4 [69.98 GiB] / in no VG: 0 [0   ]
```

lvextend

```
# lvextend -L+16380M /dev/mapper/ol-root /dev/sdb1
  Size of logical volume ol/root changed from <45.99 GiB (11773 extents) to 61.98 GiB (15868 extents).
  Logical volume ol/root successfully resized.
```

xfs_growfs

```
# xfs_growfs /
meta-data=/dev/mapper/ol-root    isize=256    agcount=14, agsize=877824 blks
         =                       sectsz=512   attr=2, projid32bit=1
         =                       crc=0        finobt=0 spinodes=0 rmapbt=0
         =                       reflink=0
data     =                       bsize=4096   blocks=12055552, imaxpct=25
         =                       sunit=0      swidth=0 blks
naming   =version 2              bsize=4096   ascii-ci=0 ftype=1
log      =internal               bsize=4096   blocks=2560, version=2
         =                       sectsz=512   sunit=0 blks, lazy-count=1
realtime =none                   extsz=4096   blocks=0, rtextents=0
data blocks changed from 12055552 to 16248832
# df -h
Filesystem           Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs             4.8G     0  4.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs                4.8G     0  4.8G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                4.8G  9.4M  4.8G   1% /run
tmpfs                4.8G     0  4.8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mapper/ol-root   62G   42G   21G  68% /
/dev/sda1           1014M  419M  596M  42% /boot
tmpfs                973M   12K  973M   1% /run/user/42
tmpfs                973M     0  973M   0% /run/user/0
```

I followed this:  https://ma.ttias.be/increase-expand-xfs-filesystem-in-red-hat-rhel-7-cento7/

Why would it work before but not now ?

Comment: This is very confusing. What part of this answer is the actual solution?

Comment: Using -L in 
lvextend -L+16380M /dev/mapper/ol-root /dev/sdb1

and not specifying /dev/mapper/ol-root in xfs_growfs.  Just use:

xfs_growfs /

Comment: It worked before because that tutorial is out of date. See the more recently posted [answer](https://serverfault.com/a/986820/126632).